# How to run a PHP script in the background after a form is submitted and redirect it to another php page?

Tags: redirect, post-redirect-get

I am using the post method in a php script as:

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="file1.php">
```

after submitting the form it runs the file1.php which takes 20-30 minutes to finish and the page hangs over here. I want to redirect this page to another page file2.php and the file1.php should be run in background without exiting it. 
Please suggest me any way to redirect it. I have tried using `header('Location: file2.php');` in file1.php but it redirects only after completing the file1.php.

Comment: Use ajax to send the form data and do the php on the serverside. It will allow you to send data without reloading your current page. You will need to use some javascript but it makes this kind of thing super easy. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: is there another way to do it without ajax???

Comment: I dont think so. php is not asynchronous but ajax is. It allows you to start something and let it do its thing while you do something else. php you have to go with the flow.

Comment: I am working for a webserver on a Linux machine. In the form action="file1.php", I am executing a command echo shell_exec("./a.out "); which takes time to complete. I am not using any output of this PHP page on further page, I just to want redirect this page and run this executable command in the background. Is there any command to redirect the user?

Answer (score 2):

**form.php**

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #console {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        overflow: auto;
        border: 1px solid #4E4E4E;
      }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="myForm">
        FirstName:
        <input type="text" name="firstName">
        <br> Second Name:
        <input type="text" name="lastName">
        <br> Phone No.:
        <input type="text" name="phoneNumber">
        <br>
     </form>

     <button id="submitMyForm">submit the form!</button>
     <br>

     <!-- JUST SOME FEEDBACK TO LET US KNOW WHAT IS SENT -->
     <h1>SENT: <span></span></h1>
     <div id="console"></div>

     <script>

         // on click of the button submit form and run php on process.php 
         $("#submitMyForm").on("click", function() {

             // get data from the form and serialize it.
             var dataFromForm = $('#myForm').serialize();

             // -------------------------------------------
             // for your information:
             // this is the format of what we are sending over
             // -------------------------------------------
             $("h1 span").append(dataFromForm + "<br>");
             // -------------------------------------------

             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 data: dataFromForm,
                 url: "process.php",
                 success: function(data) {
                     // -------------------------------------------
                     // for your information:
                     // just show what we got back from the server
                     // -------------------------------------------
                     $("#console").append("SUCCESS: " + data + "<br>");
                     // -------------------------------------------
                },
                error: function(data) {
                     // if it does not work do whatever you want.
                     console.log("ERROR");
                     console.log(data);
                }
            });

        // ------------------------------------------------ 
        // ADD THIS TO REDIRECT TO WHEREVER
        window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
        // ------------------------------------------------

        });
   </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php

 // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 // Do whatever you want here for the script. 
 // It will start running and allow you to continue doing whatever on the form page
 // you dont need to echo out anything. It is just to show its running the script
 // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    echo "
      STARTING SCRIPT: USING VARIABLES SENT FORM DATA<br>
      first name: " . $_POST['firstName'] . " <br>
      last name: " . $_POST['lastName'] . " <br>
      phone number: " . $_POST['phoneNumber'] . " <br> 
    ";

?>
```

Comment: I am new to PHP and HTML. I am working for a webserver on a Linux machine. In the form action="file1.php", I am executing a command echo shell_exec("./a.out "); which takes time to complete. I am not using any output of this PHP page on further page, I just to want redirect this page and run this executable command in the background. Is there any command to redirect the user?

Comment: I am not sure about linux but I am sure about php and html. If you submit this form with ajax it will send whatever you want to the file1.php without having to wait for a reply from file1.php. If you use php and html only, you will need to wait for file1.php script to complete whatever its doing before you can continue.

Comment: I used the $.ajax function to call prog.php and in form action i used redirect.php ...but still it goes to action or redirect.php only after completing prog.php in $.ajax...it does not redirect to redirect.php. 

I want to run prog.php in background so the page will not hang as prog.php takes time to complete the process.

Is there any way where I can include the prog.php in redirect.php to run it in background?  Simply include('prog.php'); runs on the page, I want to run it in background so that the page will not hang to wait for the completion of the prog.php

Comment: It should not wait for an ajax response. I am not sure how you are implementing the form click but if you do it like I did above, and put a redirect after your ajax call in the click function, then it will definitely not wait for a response before redirecting. I have tried it and for sure it does not wait to redirect. There is no way to do it with php at all.

Comment: BIG BIG BIG LIKE And thanks for your solution its work for me

Answer (score 1):

I used this helper static method with success for many years.

```
<?php 

namespace Libraries;

class Helper
{
    public static function redirect($location = null, $ignoreAbort = true)
    {
        header('Connection: close');
        ob_start();

        header('Content-Length: 0');
        header('Location: ' . $location);
        ob_end_flush();
        flush();

        if ($ignoreAbort) {
            ignore_user_abort(true);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how to use it.

```
<?php

namespace Controllers;

class OrderController{
    public function orderCompleted()
    {
        // If you need to send a message after redirect.
        $_SESSION["order_completed"] = "Order completed";
        // don't forget to unset the session after the message is seen.

        // Redirect should be put before the long duration script
        Helper::redirect('https://www.your-url.com/page);

        // Run in background
        // 1. Send emails
        // 2. Generate PDFs
        // 3. etc...
    }
}
```

Note:

You also need to check the PHP settings (php.ini)

Some installs do not have output_buffering on, some have 4096, some default to Off

```
# output_buffering = Off

# Use
output_buffering = 4096

# Or unlimited, but use with caution 
output_buffering = On
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `curl` if you want to execute the php code in background.

A simple example with parameters:

```
<?php    
$url = 'http://yoursite.com/yourbackground-code.php';

$fields = array(
    'param1'      => "data",
    'param2'      => "data",

);

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
//you can var_dump the result after is executed
var_dump($result);
```